# Equivalent of Linux Remind for Windows?

Tags: windows

Remind http://www.roaringpenguin.com/products/remind was featured on http://lifehacker.com/software/top/geek-to-live--keep-your-calendar-in-plain-text-with-remind-186661.php

but I'd like something on windows instead.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no** equivalent of Remind on Windows platform. However, Remind can be made to run under Windows if you [compile](http://wiki.43folders.com/index.php/Remind_FAQ#How_do_I_compile_Remind_on_Cygwin_on_Windows) it with the [Cygwin tools](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: I know it's a valid answer, but uugh.  Cygwin is such as pain.